# Why does MakeBoxes mess up RowBox ordering?

Tags: output-formatting, boxes

When I use RowBox for MakeBoxes the order of the elements is changed for TraditionalForm, if there is a plus (+) in the list of elements.

```
MakeBoxes[x, form_] = RowBox[{"b", "+", "a"}];
MakeBoxes[x, StandardForm]
MakeBoxes[x, TraditionalForm]
(* Out[2] = RowBox[{"b", "+", "a"}]
   Out[3] = RowBox[{"a", "+", "b"}] *)
```

Sometimes Mathematica really makes me wonder. Does this only happen when there is a plus in RowBox? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: FWIW, ``Block[{TraditionalFormDump`$UseNewTraditionalForm = False},MakeBoxes[x, TraditionalForm]]`` returns `RowBox[{"b", "+", "a"}]`.

Comment: FWIW^2, associating the definition to `x`, which I think it's a good idea, returns what you expect

Comment: @Leonid, you are using variables _The Google_ does not know about, therefor they do not exist. :-) But you are right. Where can you read about $UseNewTraditionalForm?

Comment: Well, I don't really know, this stuff isn't documented. I extracted that from `Trace`, can't say much more about it...

Comment: @Rojo Interesting indeed, but that will only work if `x` is at level zero or one in the first argument of `MakeBoxes`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I haven't tested, but probably attaching it to TraditionalForm, or even to `MakeBoxes` but explicitly as `DownValues`, may work

Comment: When attaching it to `TraditionalForm`'s `FormatValues` perhaps it's necessary to prepend it so it is tried first

Comment: Attaching to ``TraditionalForm`` works!

Comment: @Rojo thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I see this right, then the evil function is `` TraditionalFormDump`ordplus ``. This seems to change the order. The arguments can be extracted from a `Trace`

```
TraditionalForm[a + b]; (* Dummy call *)
TraditionalFormDump`ordplus[{{"+", "b"}, {"+", "a"}}, {}]

(* {2,1} *)
```

If we change this to give a sorted list, then your arguments are not reordered

```
ClearAll[TraditionalFormDump`ordplus]
TraditionalFormDump`ordplus[l1_, _] := Range[Length[l1]]

MakeBoxes[x, form_] = RowBox[{"b", "+", "a"}];
MakeBoxes[x, StandardForm]
MakeBoxes[x, TraditionalForm]

(* 
  RowBox[{"b", "+", "a"}]
  RowBox[{"b", "+", "a"}]
*)
```

Comment: Impressive! How did you find out about ``TraditionalFormDump`ordplus``? A trace does not give me this function. Do you have any idea why this does not happen when I associate the definition to ``x`` as Rojo mentioned?

Comment: @Friedrich I believe it does not happen because definitions associated with `x` are tried before those associated with `TraditionalForm` (just like with `UpValues`), and this special bothersome definition is attached to `TraditionalForm`'s FormatValues. Values associated with MakeBoxes (such as your definitions) are tried last.

Comment: @Friedrich You have to use `TraceInternal->True` as option to `Trace`.

Answer (score 2):

halirutan gave a very nice explanation why this only happens in `TraditionalForm` and not in `StandardForm`. For completeness I will add the workaround that Rojo mentioned: Associate the definition to `x` and not to `MakeBoxes` using `UpSet`:

```
MakeBoxes[x, form_] ^= RowBox[{"b", "+", "a"}];
```

Association with `TraditionalForm` also works:

```
Unprotect[TraditionalForm];
TraditionalForm /: MakeBoxes[x, TraditionalForm] = RowBox[{"b", "+", "a"}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also interfere with the sorting done by [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) by wrapping your boxes in [`TagBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagBox), [`InterpretationBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpretationBox) or [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox):

```
MakeBoxes[x, form_] = TagBox[RowBox[{"b", "+", "a"}], #&];
MakeBoxes[x, StandardForm]
MakeBoxes[x, TraditionalForm]
```

> TagBox[RowBox[{"b", "+", "a"}], #1 &]
>
> TagBox[RowBox[{"b", "+", "a"}], #1 &]

*(I would actually use a [`TagSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet) here, but for pedagogical reasons I avoided it.)* This avoids the need to modify an internal Mathematica symbol, as in the accepted answer (there may also be good examples where the reordering is beneficial, as in multivariate polynomials). Also, as Mr.Wizard points out, the other answers using [`TagSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet) only work when x is at the top-level. For example:

```
y /: MakeBoxes[y, form_] = RowBox[{"b", "+", "a"}];
MakeBoxes[y, TraditionalForm]
MakeBoxes[{y}, TraditionalForm]
```

> RowBox[{"b", "+", "a"}]
>
> RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"a", "+", "b"}], "}"}]

With the [`TagBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagBox) approach, the non-top level example still works:

```
MakeBoxes[{x}, TraditionalForm]
```

> RowBox[{"{", TagBox[RowBox[{"b", "+", "a"}], #1 &], "}"}]